# UITextView: disable scrolling, multiline enable

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`. I need to disable scrolling but keep multiline enabled.

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

disables multiline also.

Is there any way to achieve this?